# How to get Length of array using reflector

Tags: c#

I have library and console program, which get this is library dynamically. In library on class exist int array. So. Can I on program, use reflector get this array? This is code of library:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int [] arrayInt;
    public Class1()
    {
        arrayInt = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

This is code of program:

```
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
    Type Class1 = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.Class1") as Type;
    var testClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Class1);                
    PropertyInfo List = Class1.GetProperty("arrayInt");
    int[] arrayTest = (int[])List.GetValue(testClass, null);//throw exception here
    Console.WriteLine("Length of array: "+arrayTest.Count);
    Console.WriteLine("First element: "+arrayTest[0]);
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit the question to let us know what exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the exception because `public int[] arrayInt;` is not a property but a member variable, thus `Class1.GetProperty(...)` returns `null`.

**Alternative 1) Use `GetMember` instead of `GetProperty`**

```
MemberInfo List = Class1.GetMember("arrayInt");
```

**Alternative 2) Declare a property in `Class1`**

```
public int[] ArrayInt 
{ 
    get { return arrayInt;  }
}
```

And change ethe reflection code to:

```
PropertyInfo List = Class1.GetProperty("ArrayInt");
```

Also, please note that your code shouldn't even compile, as an array does not have a `Count` property, but only a `Length` property. The following line should give a compilation error:

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of array: "+arrayTest.Count);
```

and should read

```
Console.WriteLine("Length of array: "+arrayTest.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Class1.GetMember("arrayInt");
```

instade Of

```
Class1.GetProperty("arrayInt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a field in your original class but reflecting it as a property!

```
public class Class1
{
    public int [] arrayInt {get;set;} // <-- now this is a property
    public Class1()
    {
        arrayInt = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
    }
}
```

Only added `()` after `arrayTest.Count`:

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
Type Class1 = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.Class1") as Type;
var testClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Class1);                
PropertyInfo List = Class1.GetProperty("arrayInt"); // <!-- here you are looking for a property!
int[] arrayTest = (int[])List.GetValue(testClass, null);//throw exception here
Console.WriteLine("Length of array: "+arrayTest.Count());
Console.WriteLine("First element: "+arrayTest[0]);
```

Comment: Calling the LINQ extension method `Count()` may be more expensive than evaluating `Length`, or not?

Comment: Right. But it's a smaller change to add the braces ;-). The extra costs should nevertheless negligible if you take a look at the source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#41ef9e39e54d0d0b

Comment: Hm, it will be O(n), instead of O(1), as it iterates over the entire collection. This doesn't hurt for just 5 elements, but is significant the longer the array gets.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Actually, if you read the source code for `Count()`, it checks if the source is an `ICollection<>` and therefore has the property `Count` available, if it does, it just returns that.

Comment: Yes, I read that - I just didn't know you could actually cast `int[]` to `ICollection<int>`. Learned something new. Thanks. (It still depends though, how `ICollection.Count` is actually implemented by `Array`, but that would go too far I suppose...).

Comment: Did a little `Stopwatch` test: Calling `Length` on an `int[1000000]` took 2127 ticks, while calling `Count()` takes 11225 ticks. I tried this on two different arrays. I used `i.Length` and `j.Count()`. Well, both is under a millisecond - this was just out of interest...

Comment: I did have to check it myself ;-).