# Throw exception when get error on reflection

Tags: c#

I have library and console program. The program dynamically load library and get int array. But program throw exception. Can you help me fix it?
My library:

```
public class Class1
{
  public int [] arrayInt;
  public Class1()
  {
    arrayInt = new int[5] {1,2,3,4,5};
  }
}
```

My program:

```
    Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\TestLibrary.dll");
    Type Class1 = asm.GetType("TestLibrary.Class1") as Type;
    var testClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Class1);        
    MemberInfo[] List = Class1.GetMember("arrayInt");
    foreach (FieldInfo field in List)
    {
        if (field.FieldType.IsArray)
        {
            int[] array = (int[])field.GetValue(null);//throw exception here
            Console.WriteLine("Count of list. "+array.length);              
            foreach (var element in array)
                Console.WriteLine(element.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
```

Exception message:

> System.Reflection.TargetException: Non-static field requires a target. at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target) at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)   at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)   at Tets.Program.Main(String[] args)

P.S. Can you modified code, that first array doesn't take from Loop?

Comment: Might help if we knew what the exception was.

Comment: Where is the exception thrown? What kind of exception?

Comment: Hmmm... it looks like you have what we refer to as an "Error". Best bet to fix it is to change the broken code for some working code. Once you've done that you should be fine. (this comment/answer is designed to be as analogously devoid of useful information as the original question).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How on reflector get Length of array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982333/how-on-reflector-get-length-of-array)

Comment: No.It's not duplicate

Comment: So what don't you understand about the error message? It says you require a target so have you tried giving it a target?

Comment: Try: `field.GetValue(testClass)`

Comment: And that is exactly what the error message told you! ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In field variable in your loop you have the definition of field and when you want to get the value of field you should pass the object to the `GetValue` method, so in your code you need to write something like this

```
int[] array = (int[])field.GetValue(testClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this Field instance field (None static) you need to pass instance to [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)() method.

```
int[] array = (int[])field.GetValue(testClass);
```